# Visual Basic email system bcc mails

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making visual basic email software this software send attachment files and messages i want to send mails many companies  i am adding To field but i want to add BCC and CC mail system also include but it don't have any idea how i code for this ..if any one have a good sense of this give me a idea ....
or any other way to add multiples mails system to with the attachment of Doc CV file .... i also need to know to add filter that someone not add any other format file to send .But mainly i need to know how to Add BCC blind carbon copy system in vb and CC carbon copy system..

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Private mpMessage As MailMessage = Nothing
Private mpSMTPSvr As SmtpClient = Nothing

'------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-> Send The Message
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
MailerHost = "Addrss-of-your-emailer-host-server"
mpMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
mpMessage.Body = "Message body text goes here"
If Trim(SenderNameValue) <> "" Then
  mpMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("senderemail@hotmail.com", SenderNameValue)
  mpMessage.Sender = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("senderemail@hotmail.com", SenderNameValue)
Else
  mpMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("senderemail@hotmail.com", "Name_Unspecified")
  mpMessage.Sender = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("senderemail@hotmail.com", "Name_Unspecified")
End If
mpMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
mpMessage.Subject = "[WEB-REPONSE] - Correspondence via Website response form."
mpMessage.To.Add(Trim("recipient@yahoo.com"))
mpMessage.CC.Add(Trim("secretary@yahoo.com"))
mpMessage.BCC.Add(Trim("manager@yahoo.com"))
Try
  mpSMTPSvr.Send(mpMessage)
  SendStandardCommunicae = True
  Catch ex As Net.Mail.SmtpException
  ReturnErrorid = eEML_NETWORKERRORSENDINGEMAIL
  ReturnErrorText = "A network error occurred whilst trying to send your message, please check your details for syntax errors and try again later.<br />If the error occurs consistently please contact the site administrator or use an alternative method of contact.<br /><br />"
  ReturnErrorText = ReturnErrorText & "Extra Information:" & ex.Message
End Try
```